# Automatically add close quote in visual studio like resharper does

Tags: configuration, ide, visual-studio-2010, quotes

can not find this option in new studio (2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't built in to VS2010 - an add-in such as Visual Assist (and you've already mentioned Resharper yourself) will get this for you.  Of course, that won't help for the Express versions of VS2010 since add-ins aren't supported in those SKUs.

Answer (score 11):

Options-
Text Editor-
HTML-
Formatting-
Insert attributes values quotes when typing

Comment: I've not used vs2010 but this is where the option is in vs2008

Answer (score -2):

This is probably because you need to [download it](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/EA4AC039-1B5C-4D11-804E-9BEDE2E63ECF?SRC=VSIDE) first, then install it. The next time you run VS2010, you should be able to start using ReSharper automatically.